Who threw the plate in that made the Egel Zahav עֵגֶל זָּהָב come out?
Yehuda haKohen relays:

The Hebrew worldview associates Yosef with cattle. In Moshe’s brakhot
to the different tribes at the end of Sefer D’varim, we see Yosef
likened to a shor – a bull. Our Sages teach that when Moshe raised
Yosef’s sarcophagus from the bottom of the Nile, he had written the
words “aleh shor” – “arise bull” on a metal plate and then cast that
plate into the river. Yosef’s body then rose to the surface and Moshe
was able to fulfill the nation’s oath to bring it with us out of
Egypt.
The Midrash Tanḥuma teaches that someone retrieved this metal plate
and brought it to Sinai. When the people demanded that Aharon
construct a new god to replace Moshe, Aharon collected their gold and
began to melt it down. Then this man threw the metal plate with the
words “aleh shor” into the fire and the Golden Calf emerged.

Who was this man who inherited the golden plate and caused the golden calf to emerge? What was his name?

His name was Michah, per Midrash Tanchuma, cited by Rashi to Shemos 32:4:

There are some who say that Micah the idolator mentioned in Judges ch.
17, was there, who had been drawn forth from the foundations of a
building in Egypt where he was nearly crushed. He had in his
possession a “supernatural name” (שם) and a plate upon which Moses had
written: “Come up, ox, come up, ox!” in order to raise the coffin of
Joseph who is compared to an ox (cf. Deuteronomy 33:17) out of the
Nile, and he cast it (the plate) into the melting pot and the calf
(the young ox) came out (ויצא העגל הזה) (Midrash Tanchuma, Ki Tisa
19).


There is an extra detail. He was a child and Moshe complained to God that innocent children were being killed. God explained that he arranged for those with wicked souls to be the ones who are killed but Moshe insisted that God save the child. The child would then hang out with Moshe and observed him raise the coffin.

Dan v'Yosef

So Micah is ben Dan or ben Ephraim ... or?

Rashi says that some people say he was Delilah's son (he's returning the  silver that he stole from her, his mother) ... and that they're wrong:
https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Judges.17.3.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

(He did use to call her "MOM" ... which I found to be astoundingly strange)

בַּיָּמִ֣ים הָהֵ֔ם אֵ֥ין מֶ֖לֶךְ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל
